# Unterminated string constant windows script host vbscript error

Tags: vbscript

I am getting an error unterminated string constant 800A0409 from windows script host because of the "em dash" character `—`. It seems to work fine from other computer there were no errors and also when I copy paste the em dash symbol in excel VBA it turns into a "?". I have tried using the ASCII equivalent; when doing so I did not get the error but instead getting a weird character: `‿`

Code:

```
If InStr(xLine, "—" ) > 0 Then
    ReplaceEmDash = Replace(xLine, "—", "-")
```

Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this should work

```
Dim EmDash
    EmDash = ChrW(&h2014)

If InStr(xLine, EmDash) > 0 Then
    ReplaceEmDash = Replace(xLine, EmDash, "-")
....
```

Comment: Still getting the weird character, is this EmDash = ChrW(&h2014) right?

Comment: @dirknowitzki, i've search several sources (and the [usual one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash#Common_dashes)) and so it seems. I tested your posted code, and with `WScript.Echo replace(ChrW(&h2014) & "[testing]" & ChrW(&h2014), ChrW(&h2014), "-")` As you are removing the EmDash, maybe the problem is in the remaining input line.

Comment: thanks for the reply! I tried to run the script with just the symbol — itself from another computer and there were no errors or weird characters. Any ideas?